# Copy emacs font settings to another computer

Tags: emacs, fonts

I want to copy over the emacs fonts settings from one computer to another - any ideas how to do this.

I did C-u C-x = to get the following :

character: r (0162, 114, 0x72) 
charset: ascii (ASCII (ISO646 IRV)) 
 code point: 114 
     syntax: word 
   category: a:ASCII   l:Latin 
buffer code: 0x72 
  file code: 0x72 (encoded by coding system undecided-unix) 
       font: -Adobe-Courier-Medium-R-Normal--12-120-75-75-M-70-ISO8859-1

Now I want to replicate this on another machine
(Running GNU emacs 23.1.1) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default font using:

```
(set-default-font "-Adobe-Courier-Medium-R-Normal--12-120-75-75-M-70-ISO8859-1")
```

Put this in the target machine's .emacs file, or you can switch at will if you simply execute the line (paste in any buffer, put cursor after `)` and use `C-x C-e`).

Comment: This doesn't set all the properties to match - but for the most part I don't notice any differences :) Thanks !